# Node path output different value on Linux and windows

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, operating-system

In webpack, when you set target to node and set node.option.dirname to false, it will generate static value for __dirname taking the value at the compile time:

For example, if __dirname was used in build/routes.js, it I will be set:

```
const __dirameGenerated = "build\\routes"
path.join(__dirameGenerated,'/../../../client/dist/somepath')
```

However, the above code will  not output the same of every os.

on windows,

```
> '..\\client\\dist\\somepath'
```

on Linux,

```
> '../../client/dist/somepath'
```

How do I make sure path.join always output the same value regadless of the system os?

Comment: `path.join` is creating the path using the native OS directory delimeter so that the path will behave correctly in whatever context you use it on that OS. Why do you want them to be the same?

Comment: Because I am developing the code on windows and deploying it on linux

Comment: If you develop the code on Windows then deploy it on Linux, then on Linux it will generate the correct path for Linux. If you test it on Windows, it should work on Windows since the path is correct on Windows. So I'm still not sure why it's a problem. Can you indicate specifically what problem it has caused in your development? Then that would make the issue clear.

Comment: Did you try deploying to Linux? Does the app crash? Because I never had any problem doing so

Comment: @lurker is right. If your problem is "I want the paths to be identical just because I want it, despite my app working fine", then there's no problem.

Comment: There is an index.html  resource file inside ../client/dist/somepath. On windows, it is found there because the correct path is used. on Linux, it searches for the index.html one folder above the tree so it is not found and express replies with 404 Not found

Comment: @lurker yes it crashes on linux.  The different is the extra '..' for the linux output

Comment: So the problem isn't the delimeter, but the actual location of the file? You should state that in your question.

Comment: Try `path.resolve` instead of `path.join` ?

Comment: The nodejs krewe went to a lot of trouble to make things work on both DOS (windows) and Linux. A LOT of trouble. Because DOS. Most developers don't have the problems you're having. With respect, you're probably overcomplicating something.

Comment: It looks like, for some reason, node believes that `client/dist/somepath` is at a different relative path in one OS versus the other. So when the path is statically generated on the Windows platform, where is that path (starting at `client`) relative to the point of the path being generated, versus where it is when the code is deployed on Linux?

Answer (score 0):

you should be using path.separator utility in that case if you want the same output but path.join should handle ideally cross platform things

Answer (score 0):

**Use `path.resolve` to traverse the filesystem**

Using `path.resolve` lets you move around the file system but maintain cross-platform compatibility. As per the documentation you can think of it as a series of cd commands that output a single path at the end.

```
path.resolve('../', '/../', '../')
// '/home' on Linux
// '/Users' on OSX
// 'C:\\Users' on Windows
```

Answer (score 0):

As written above use path.resolve, but also switch to WSL Ubuntu in Windows10 for better build performance and compatibility. Use it in the new Windows Terminal, its awesome.